# Write accent mark in .shp and .dxf filename

Tags: arcpy, python, utf-8

I'm trying to export with python 2.7 some shapefiles and CAD files that could have specials characters in their filename, like accent marks. In example, I want to have this:

```
MMT_LT_1215_20101004_05_Crespià_Esponellà.shp
```

But when I export the files the filename is like this:

```
MMT_LT_1215_20101004_05_CrespiÓ_EsponellÓ.shp
```

I've already changed the encoding to UTF-8 with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, but it don't result anyway. The fact is that when I create the directory that must contain the files and has the same file name, the accent marks are writed correctly like in the first example. I'm not sure if I have to use the encode() or decode() functions to face that.

Comment: I think you should avoid special charachters in file names. Would normalizing the charachters be an option? `unicodedata.normalize('NFD','á å ä Ö').encode('ascii','ignore').decode('utf-8')` output: `'a a a O'`

Comment: I guess it would be an option, but I tried this `unicodedata.normalize('NFD', nomMuni1).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')` and the result is the same.   nomMuni1 is the variable that contains the text to normalize.

Comment: The Shapefile specification actually states that names should be 8.3 compliant, so using UTF-8 names actually presents a portability risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should avoid special characters in file names. You can normalize them using [unicode.normalize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize), for example:

```
from unicodedata import normalize
somestring = 'á å ä Ö'
somestring = normalize('NFD',somestring).encode('ascii','ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

`'á å ä Ö'` will now be `'a a a O'`